# expected function body after function declarator cs50

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)

if (x > y)
{
    printf("X is greater than Y\n");
}
else
{
    printf("X is less than Y\n");
}
```

Whenever I try to compile this code, it's giving me the error "expected function body after function declarator". please help as this is my first time coding. Error listed below.

```
conditions.c:9:1: error: expected function body after function declarator
if (x > y)
^
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'conditions' failed
make: *** [conditions] Error 1
```

Comment: The function body should start with `{` and end with `}`. Yours starts with `if`.

Answer (score 2):

When defining a function in C, the contents of the body of the function must be enclosed in braces.  So, in your case, you just need to include the braces:

```
int main(void)
{
    /* Do something with x and y here */

    if (x > y)
    {
        printf("X is greater than Y\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("X is less than Y\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: @komailahmed Furthermore every executable expressions have to be inside of a function.

Answer (score 0):

A function definition in C is expressed in the following basic form:

1. A *declarator*, which you have as `int main(void)`
2. A *compound statement*, which you don't have—a compound statement is a sequence of declarations and statements enclosed in curly braces (`{` and `})`. You just have a naked if/else statement.

There are other problems with your program, though:

- What are `x` and `y`? You need to tell the compiler what kind of values they are with *declarations* and then say *what* values they are with *initialization statements*. If you want them to be the integers 1 and 2, declare them with `int x; int y;` or `int x, y;` and initialize them with `x = 1;` and `y = 2;`.
- What's the `main` function going to return? Functions (except for void functions) aren't just lists of instructions; they're mathematical operations that give (or *return*) some result. Your declarator `int main(void)` promised that the function would give an `int`, but you don't have any statement that would let it do so. The normal way of ending a `main` function is `return 0;`, which tells the computer, "Okay, the program finished without running into any problems."

In summary: enclose your if/else statement in curly braces, declare and initialize your variables, and end with a return statement.